# toggle html button pause and resume functions

Tags: javascript, html

Im playing an audio file and I want to pause and resume this file.I have the pause() and resume() functions and i have the following html button

```
<a id="btn_pause" class="btn btn-success btn-large " onclick="$('#audioLayerControl')[0].pause()"><i class="icon-pause icon-white"></i></a>
```

I want to toggle the button where the user when clicking back the pause button the resume() function is called.
how could that happen??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jQuery, so removing the inline event handler and adding a proper one is better.
Then check the `audio.paused` property so if the audio is paused

```
$('#btn_pause').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var audio = $('#audioLayerControl').get(0);

    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
    } else {
        audio.pause();
    }

});
```

Comment: it's pausing but not playing again

Comment: You mentioned a `resume()` method? I just used the `play()` method as that is generally what is used. How do you play the audio when it starts ?